# Which directory should .whl packages go in a Pycharm Project?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, cx-freeze

I've been trying to import cx_Freeze into my Pygame project I'm making in PyCharm. I tried importing it the same way I imported Pygame (through the Project Interpreter) but "cx_Freeze" doesn't come up when I search for it. So, instead I just downloaded the cx_Freeze package through the website.

So, my question is: if I want to move the package from my Downloads Folder into my project via Explorer, which directory should it go into? My first instinct is to put it in venv/Lib/site-packages (where pygame is) but I don't want to mess with things I don't fully understand.

Comment: You have to install cx_Freeze before you can import it. In Pycharm, open Pygame project, open Terminal, type: python -m pip install cx_Freeze. This will install it where it's supposed to go and should include all dependencies too. If you wanna know where it is after type: pip show cx_Freeze –

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy the whl file, install it instead. Open a terminal from Pycharm, it will open it with your project interpreter, then find from the terminal the wheel file and run:

```sh
python -m pip install wheel                        # only first time
python -m pip install wheel_file.whl               # for each library you want to install
```

This is the correct way of installing wheel files and it will ensure all required modules and hooks are met.

Answer (score -1):

do

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and it can be in any of the path shown

Comment: I've tried doing that (putting it in the site-packages directory) but it still seems to be having the same issue. Maybe I should put it in Include directory?